# Rails 4: undefined method `result' for #<TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Array)>

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am kind of stuck with this error. Postgres is running, the Rails server too, and I get the following NoMethodError on any page:

```
undefined method `result' for #<TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Array)>
```

The application trace is not really explicit:

```
config/environments/development.rb:45:in `call'
```

Extracted source (around line #45):

```
   previous_level = Rails.logger.level
   Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'].index("/assets/") == 0
   @app.call(env)
 ensure
   Rails.logger.level = previous_level
 end
```

It might be related to the PostgreSQL adapter.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just got it after a while of tracking down to the bug source: it was a problem of character encoding between US-ASCII and UTF-8... a 'space' was not really a 'space' in my Gemfile.